# Testing a t-statistic from an unconditional linear mixed effects regression (LMER) model

Tags: statistical-significance, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme

Trying to figure out if I should conduct an Hierarchical Linear Modeling [(HLM)](http://www.tqmp.org/RegularArticles/vol08-1/p052/p052.pdf) analysis with a data set. The output for the unconditional model gives me this. 
[image]

Yes, I know the intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC) is large, but I'm trying to determine 'significance' of the model without the ICC. If the model is significant and the ICC is large, I know to go through the analysis. So what I'm looking for/ hoping to get advice on is how to comfortably interpret that t value, which seems of rather small magnitude.

Any and all advice for this is appreciated, but actual answers are the best :) ;)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are asking here. What do you mean by the 'significance of the model'? significance with respect to what?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to determine whether the model is significant based on the t test for the fixed intercept. However, the insignificance of the fixed intercept only indicates that the population average of the outcome is not significantly different from 0. In contrast, the variance estimation results reveal that the outcome varies a lot both within and across schools, with an ICC of 0.24.